# Having trouble with port application blocking

Tags: python, windows, port, vlan

any ideas on how to block a network port from being used, or one that
is currently in use? For example, say I want to block port 23 from
being used. by used, I mean allowing connections to or from it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: for the Windows environment specifically on a VLAN

Comment: does the solution need to be written as a python scripts as you have tagged python

Comment: Yes it does, where it will be activated/deactivated with a button in the GUI(PyQt). @AlexanderRD

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Windows Server 2016 @АндрейЧереваткин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution need to be done via the command line however you can use python's os library to run scripts. this [link](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2011/10/block-ports-from-the-command-line/) is too a similar problem (just with a different port) so you can adapt that command then run it by the following script

```
import os
# specify the command prompt command you need to be run
command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="BlockAIM" protocol=TCP  dir=out remoteport=23 action=block'
# assign variable to the command
output = os.popen2(command)
# To get output call output.read()
```

the following script blocks outgoing requests so you will need to repeat the process with dir=in